# Handling SafeArea in ReactNative on iPhone X

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, iphone-x

In my ReactNative app, I'm using "SafeAreaView" to restrict my content in the visible area. My app runs in landscape mode. Look at the image
[image]

My app has FlatList with 2 Items rendered. If you notice the FlatList (in green color), on the left it has some padding of 20 pixels and on the right, it has notch (though it has padding of 20 pixels to the border). Due to notch on right my FlatList don't seem to be centered. 
Is there a way to handle the content size considering the notch area?

Comment: can you add code here?

Comment: If your concern is only about iPhone with notches then you add the differences of the notch and bottom bar to the bottom bar margin/padding to center the flat list.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your Flatlists with an inner View between the Flatlists and the SafeAreaView and add the padding the inner View e.g

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 24, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    {/* your flatlists here */}
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

this should make it look more natural.

Comment: It  won't be centered in iPhone X as it has a notch. It will show uneven on the side where notch is there.

Comment: in this case, try using useSafeAreaInsets from react-native-safe-area-context
    
-> const paddingRight = useSafeAreaInsets().right + 24;

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iphone-x-helper

`getBottomSpace()` and `getStatusBarHeight()`